# Can we read in data from a database like MySQL into Omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am working on creating a network in Omnet++ consisting of mobile hosts.What I want to know is it possible for one to read in data from MySQL and use for message passing between different hosts.

In short, is it possible to connect a Omnet++ project to MySQL?

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: could u give me a link or some source code which could do the same?

Comment: Questions asking for links to off-site resources are off-topic so no I cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

As OMNeT++ is just a C++ library, you can link your simulation with whatever other library you want including the MySQL client libraries. The code you need to use to read from MySQL is documented in the MySQL docs. As for example to connect to mysql, I highly recommend the samples/database folder in OMNeT++.